# Clang optimizations when no return statement: if(false) is entered?

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, clang++

Here is a small working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string f(int i) {
  if (i == 0)
    return "zero";
  if (i == 1)
    return "one";
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  (void)argv;
  std::cout << "Passed " << f(argc - 1) << " arguments." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling without optimizations:

```
$ clang++ ./return_optims_ifs.cpp -o test
./return_optims_ifs.cpp:10:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.

$ ./test
Passed zero arguments.

$ ./test a
Passed one arguments.

$ ./test a b
[1]    20447 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  ./test a b
```

Okay, that was clearly expected.

Now, compiling *with* optimizations:

```
$ clang++ ./return_optims_ifs.cpp -o test -O3
./return_optims_ifs.cpp:10:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.

$ ./test
Passed zero arguments.

$ ./test a
Passed one arguments.

$ ./test a b
Passed one arguments.
```

Wait, what ?!

What kind of optimizations could just assume i want the last if() to be a "default case" ?

How could I disable this optim, to *really* see the crashes due to bad code, instead of having them shadowed ?

```
$ clang --version
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, if the second `if` is reached, it must be true, otherwise it would be undefined behaviour. So a compiler can optimize the `if` away and return `"one"` whenever the first `if` is false. The compiler warns you about it. What else do you want?

Comment: What says the code has to crash?  You get a warning from the compiler about your undefined behavior which is enough to tell you you need to fix the code, it even tells you where.  You can use `-Werror` to force it to become an error as well.

Comment: It already warns you at compile time, what more do you want? Stop expecting specific behavior from UB.

Comment: Once you use undefined behaviour, there are *no* restriction on what the compiler is allowed to do. It could, should it so choose, format your hard disk and it would *still* be compatible with the ISO standard.

Comment: Actually I would just have expected the same behaviour than with debug : a crash. Considering it's not the case, it's just as if optimization weren't reliable. But anyway, i can see the UB problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers optimisations are strongly architecture-version dependent.

However I think I can still provide an answer to your question.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/yKGUBs) you can see an online disassemble (with clang 4.0.1).

The `f` function will be decomposed in the following:

```
f[abi:cxx11](int):                           # @f[abi:cxx11](int)
        lea     rax, [rdi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rax
        test    esi, esi
        je      .LBB0_1                    // <=== JUMP NOT EQUAL
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 2], 101
        mov     word ptr [rax], 28271
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], 3
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + 19], 0
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        mov     dword ptr [rdi + 16], 1869768058
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], 4
        mov     byte ptr [rdi + 20], 0
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

As you can see, the conditional branch is the instruction `je .LBB0_1` which jump if `i != 0`. In the other case (`i == 0`) the function body will continue.

In other words, the code will be optimised as:

```
if (i != 0)
  return "one";
else 
  return "zero";
```

That why you probably obtain your *unexpected* result. Your `"a b"` input will execute the case `2 != 0` returning `"one"`.

### Important Note

It's very important to consider that your code produces an *undefined behaviour*. That means the behaviour of your code could be anything. On another compiler/architecture the output result may be different.

That kind of code must be strongly avoided.

Comment: Okay, I can see what would be going on.
BTW if I only have the first if(), then the function will return "one". So the "if" is just elided if it's alone.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of optimizations could just assume i want the last if() to be a "default case" ?

Your function *must* return a value, because the signature says so.

And from the source we can see that the options are `return "zero"` and `return "one"`. So if it isn't `"zero"` it *has to be* `"one"` because there are no more alternatives.

The only other option is that your program is invalid. But that is not allowed so cannot happen, right? At least the optimizer may assume that it never happens.

Comment: Functions do not always return values (think about throw or exit). That is the kind of behaviour one would expect, just like it happens without optimizations.